# Is there a way to make pos_type and off_type to be an int64_t using traits?

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, traits, large-file-support

I am trying to understand what traits are, for example expressions like `typedef typename traits_type::off_type off_type` in the GNU implementation of `fstream`.

This question came up when I was working with files larger than 2/4 GB. I found that recompiling the STL library, with the appropriate flags usually solves the large file issues.

Comment: Can you expand on what 'flags' exactly you used and why you used them?  Understanding the specifics will help us give an answer that makes more sense to you.  Also, you should mention what the `pos_type` and `off_type` you refer to in your title are related to.

Comment: I have solved the large file support issue, this question is not about that. Now I am trying to understand what traits are and how to use them in STL. As for your question, I added some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits are a way of "adding" properties to existing types. Let's say we are creating a container type, which contains a typedef to tell its contained data type. The classic way would be:

```
template <class T>
struct Cont { typedef T contained_type; }
```

This has the disadvantage that we have to create our class just to contain the typedef - eg. third party containers and basic types cannot be used by code that assumes `Cont::contained_type` type. So we introduce a traits struct, which adds an indirection in the process:

```
template <class C>
struct container_traits; // this struct would contain the contained_type for container C

template <class T>
struct Cont { ... } // no typedef here

template <class T>
struct container_traits<Cont<T> >
{
  typedef T contained_type; // by this, we say that the contained_type of Cont<T> is T
};

template <class T, unsigned N>
struct container_traits<T[N]>
{
  // this is the advantage of traits - we can add information for arrays, which can have no member typedefs
  typedef T contained_type;
};
```

Alos, the traits template can be a parameter of algorithms using it, which permits us to use different traits with a single data type (see the `std::string` class).

That said, I don't believe traits have much to do with 64-bit systems.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! As for "I don't believe traits have much to do with [..] off_type", I had a look at the GNU implementation and found: typedef typename traits_type::off_type off_type. What does traits mean here?

Comment: OK, `off_type` is defined by a traits class. I just thought you shouldn't need changing traits in any way on 64bit systems, the standard types should work. Note that eg. stream classes with different traits are different types and will interfere with each other (like `cin` and `wcin`).